# SQL Server Import and Export Wizard - Error Message when Opened

Tags: sql-server, import, export, wizard

When I click the shortcut, I get this message:

> TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
>
> An error occurred which the SQL Server Integration Services Wizard was not prepared to handle.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Filen eller assemblyen 'Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.ScaleHelper, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' eller en af dens afhængigheder kunne ikke indlæses. Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet. (DTSWizard)

Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.ScaleHelper SQL Server Import and Export Wizard

My SQL Server 2022 installation works very well but the Import/Export Wizard continues to fail no matter what I do . I have looked 'everywhere' in Google for a solution but all suggestions seems not to work.

Any help to resolve this error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok - I will try to clarify!

Comment: On my pc I have:

Microsoft SQL Server 2019
Microsoft SQL Server 2022
Microsoft SQL Server Tools 2019

Under Microsoft SQL Server Tools 2019 I have an icon called SQL Server Management Studio 19 - this I use to access my SQL Server databases and it works fine.

Under Microsoft SQL Server 2022 I have SQL Server 2022 Import and Export Data and when I click this, i get the above error. 

Can it be due to version 2019/2022 that I get the error?

I have been working with SQL Server for some time now but it still seems a bit confusing to me 

Comment: I would be very happy for some help to get it work 